# Visual Studio equivalent of TeamCity configuration parameters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, teamcity, yaml

Currently we have a solution on TeamCity that has a lot of Configuration Parameters (which are in the build step called Build Parameters).

We have a yaml config file in the solution that gets many values from these parameters using this notation:

$(VARIABLE_NAME)

I would like to test that my code and configuration files work without putting them on TeamCity, and also without replacing all the parameters in the yaml configuration files with their hardcoded values.

So my question is, is there a way to add configuration/build parameters in Visual Studio 2013 so that my yaml configs will be able to "see" these variables?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this on my own.  There are only two ways to pass parameters to a C# program: environment variables and arguments for the main method.  In this case, TeamCity was actually adding in arguments that looked like this, if you entered them in on the command line:

`-VARIABLE_NAME: value -VARIABLE_NAME2: value2`

There was then an external method someone else on my project had written, that could take these arguments and replace every "$(VARIABLE_NAME)" string in the yaml config with the value.

I could therefore add in the TeamCity configuration parameters locally by simply passing them in as command line arguments.